# How are the limits of the center of gravity chart established?

Tags: weight-and-balance

When one views a center of gravity limit chart, in this case a C-182T chart, one notices that the forward C.G. line has two small bends in it, one around 2250# mark and the other around the 2675# mark. Why the two bends in the forward C.G. limit line? What has happened at these two points?

[image: Center-of-gravity limits for Cessna 182T]

Image from: [C-182T POH](http://axenty.com/resources/PIM/C182T%20PIM%20%28NAV%20III%29.pdf) pg. 211

Comment: Could you perhaps add an image or a link to the chart in question?

Comment: I think it's likely that the limit actually curves but the engineers decided to make straight lines out of them in the manual so pilots could interpolate them better.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the area presented by a deflected control surface is the tangent of the angle of deflection (opposite side of "triangle"). The increase of area presented is linear to the angle of deflection.  Coefficient of Lift is also linear with increased AOA, so yeah, they may be actually straight.

Answer (score 14):

These "bends" (or sloped straight lines) are due to various structural constrains on the aircraft.

[image]

In level flight, the sum of forces must be zero:

Lift<sub>Wing</sub> - Weight - Lift<sub>Tail</sub> = 0

The summation of moment should also be zero, otherwise the plane will pitch up or down.

The wing has a structural limitation, i.e. a maximum loading. Solving the above equations for constant Lift<sub>Wing</sub> yields a slopped straight line. **This is the "bend" portion you see in the graph.**

Drawing these lines (shown as colored lines here) on top of a weight and balance graph yields:
[image]

The resulted graph is the **intersection** of the various constraints.

In the C-182 graph, there are five constraints (five edges). Wing loading and tail loading is used as an example here, since I do not know what is the actual constraint used by the engineers. Another possibility is strength of the nose gear.

Main landing gear loading and aft tipping limit would have resulted in a downward slope, which does not correspond to the given graph.

---

Source: [Center of Gravity Limitations (PDF)](http://www.smartcockpit.com/download.php?path=docs/&file=Center_Of_Gravity_Limitations.pdf)

Comment: Interesting information, but it doesn't describe _why_ there are two distinct kinks in the graph for the C182, which is what OP asked.

Comment: @FreeMan I have edited the answer to relate to the OP's graph. It was already in the answer, but might not be very clear.

Comment: I'll take your word for it.  ;)  That graph looks like it's got about 8 dimensions, and even after 4 semesters of calculus (a _looong_ time ago), my brain doesn't want to wrap around it. Don't worry about me, though. If others are having difficulty, more explanation, if it's just me, let it go.

Comment: Are you sure it's not about limiting stick forces??? If you post speculation, please spell out clearly that you are guessing.

Comment: @PeterKampf limiting stick force would be mathematically equivalent to limiting tail loading.

Comment: @kevin: Mathematically, yes. Unless you include pitch trim. Now set pitch trim and try to maneuver the aircraft without exceeding stick forces. To make sure that enough control margin is left, the cg position must be limited. Tail loads can vary a lot for the same stick force. BTW: The wing and tail load limits line are **much** more shallow than the limits in the Cessna 182 chart.

Comment: @PeterKampf: I didn't say the graph is to scale, or did I?

Answer (score 4):

There could be two reasons:

1. Performance: The more forward c.g. location demands more speed, so the wing can create enough lift to counteract the downforce from the tail. To keep the minimum speed below the [61 knots mandated by FAR part 23](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:1.0.1.3.10#se14.1.23_149), the forward c.g. location at high gross weight needs to be restricted.
2. Stick forces: A more forward c.g. location translates into bigger elevator deflection angles for maneuvering. Again, the airworthiness requirements put lower and [upper limits](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:1.0.1.3.10#se14.1.23_1143) on them, and it could be that the upper limits are exceeded with the combination of high gross weight and forward c.g. location.