# Why is the top left corner cut off on the cg location envelope for small airplanes?

Tags: aircraft-design, weight-and-balance, cg

Why does the PA-28 C.G. envelope have the top left corner cut off rather than allowing higher weights at a forward C.G. like it does at the aft C.G.?

[image]

([source](http://www.fireair.co.uk/images/W&B.png))

Comment: It isn't just small airplanes, I've seen lots of business jets that look the same.

Comment: The 727, 747, and 767 also have such an envelope.

Comment: Please attribute the image with the source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are the limits of the center of gravity chart established?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15180/how-are-the-limits-of-the-center-of-gravity-chart-established)

Answer (score 10):

With "top left corner" you mean the combination of a heavy airplane and a forward cg location.

This is to limit maximum stick forces. Manoeuvring (= flight at a specified load factor ≠ 1)  needs force proportional to the distance between the cg and the [neutral point](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6302/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-aerodynamic-centre/6338#6338) ("static margin") and the mass of the airplane. There are several situations in which certification requires not to exceed specific maximum forces. For example, [FAR Part 23.145](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=dba8d2d66ee80f512d872dcdaac69d7c&mc=true&node=se14.1.23_1145&rgn=div8) says:

> (b) Unless otherwise required, it must be possible to carry out the
>   following maneuvers without requiring the application of single-handed
>   control forces exceeding those specified in §23.143(c). The trimming
>   controls must not be adjusted during the maneuvers:

[...]

> (c) At speeds above VMO/MMO, and up to the maximum speed shown under
>   §23.251, a maneuvering capability of 1.5 g must be demonstrated to
>   provide a margin to recover from upset or inadvertent speed increase.

Another would be out of trim situations as those in [Part 23.255](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=dba8d2d66ee80f512d872dcdaac69d7c&mc=true&n=sp14.1.23.b&r=SUBPART&ty=HTML#se14.1.23_1255):

> (f) In the out-of-trim condition specified in paragraph (a) of this
>   section, it must be possible from an overspeed condition at VDF/MDF to
>   produce at least 1.5 g for recovery by applying not more than 125
>   pounds of longitudinal control force using either the primary
>   longitudinal control alone or the primary longitudinal control and the
>   longitudinal trim system.

Comment: Is Vdf the demonstrated diving speed? Also, where may one find such information if it is not in the POH nor in the TCDS?

Comment: @Pugz: Yes, VDF is the demonstrated dive speed, so Mach effects can be included to lower the dive speed from the usual VD value. For the PA-28 the regular VD applies (VDF/MDF are used for jets only). Part 23.335 defines those speeds (but not VDF explicitly).

Comment: Very cool, thanks!